# Can cgi scripts be downloaded by an attacker?

Tags: scripting, cgi

I have a rather simple question but could not find an answer on the internet so far:
Is there any way an attacker can download a CGI Script (Perl, Python, whatever) from a webpage?

Or in other words: Is it a security risk to have sensible information (e.g. access keys to another service) within a cgi script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way an attacker can download a CGI Script (Perl, Python, whatever) from a webpage?

The design of web servers tries to prevent this, but the design of web applications should assume this. - i.e. It's not how it's supposed to work, but it's not at all uncommon.  Whether or not it's possible depends on why you're asking the question.

There *may* be a way for a *particular* hacker to download a script from *your* webpage, if he had an attack vector that was worth their time to do so.

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/177951/274366) to another question (though relating to PHP, principles are the same), explains in a good amount of detail some of the factors that can lead to an exploit.

> Is it a security risk to have sensible information (e.g. access keys to another service) within a cgi script?

Yes.  While there's always risk, and the acceptability of that risk depends on your application and specific tradeoffs, this particular scenario has two major flaws (if not more):

1. If anything went wrong with your server, or CGI handler, you could have a public facing text file
2. It's just *so, so easy*, just to *not* put the private key there.

Even if the private key only accessed a VM on a free tier which did nothing but return the weather in your local city, you should at least employ a model where private keys are not accessible by the web server user (i.e. www-data, etc).  i.e. You could have your CGI handler simply pass the paramaters/arguments to another local service to parse and invoke the actions required.